# Can you extend only RawRepresentables which use Strings for the raw value type?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I'm trying to write an extension that extends enums based on strings.  The way I know to extend all enumerations is to extend RawRepresentable, but I want it restricted to strings-only.

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawRepresentable.RawValue == String{

    func foo(){

        let myRawValue:String = self.rawValue

    }
}
```

So how do you specify a 'where' clause to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend just `RawRepresentable`s based on `String`s, the `where` clause is simply `where RawValue == String`:

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {

    func foo() {
        let myRawValue:String = self.rawValue
        print(myRawValue)
    }
}


enum Flintstone: String {
    case fred, wilma, pebbles
}

Flintstone.fred.foo()  // fred
```

Comment: [[head-slap]] How did I miss that?!  Thanks!